# Using Parse JavaScript SDK with Google Chrome App

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, google-chrome-app

I'm starting a new project and I'd like to create a Google Chrome App. The app data are stored on Parse.com. I tried to import the Parse JS SDK in the Chrome app but I got that error:

*window.localStorage is not available in packaged apps. Use chrome.storage.local instead*.

Parse SDK uses localStorage, but Chrome app requires a different api. How I can solve this issues?

Any help will be very appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

See [Create Parse sessions using Chrome storage not localstorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32933474/create-parse-sessions-using-chrome-storage-not-localstorage/33445018#33445018)

I came across the same problem. **Since Parse 1.6, they started to support different type of storage.**

1. You will need to write your own storage controller based on whatever storage api you are using(`chrome.storage.local for example`), and meet Parse's storage controller interface.
2. Then you need to set Parse to use your storage before initialize it.

See here for more details:
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-JS/issues/72

Good luck!