# Create Parse sessions using Chrome storage not localstorage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, session, parse-platform, google-chrome-extension

I am building a Chrome Extension that requires Parse User sessions. Because localstorage is domain specific, I need to use chrome.storage so it can be accessed while on any site.

The current Parse Javascript SDK uses localstorage to store a user object and create sessions. How can I switch this so Parse uses chrome.storage?

Here's my current thinking atm:

```
on login
   store sessiontoken in chrome.storage
```

Then when I visit a site:

```
if chrome.storage.sessiontoken
    create parse session with chrome.storage.sessiontoken
```

I was wondering if anyone's come across a simpler way?

I would love to just do:
window.localstorage = chrome.storage

But imagine that will lead to problems. Anyone solved this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you need to write your own storage controller(with chrome api ofcourse) and then let parse to use it.

**Since this thread is newer, here's the detailed solution:**

By default, Parse javascript SDK use `window.localStorage` api to store data.
However, in Chrome app, `localStorage` is replaced by `chrome.storage` api, which offers better **non-blocking** storage solution.

**Parse SDK is actually prepared for different type of storage(both sync and async), and let your set your own custom storage controller**

As **@andrewimm (from github)** pointed out, you need to call `Parse.CoreManager.setStorageController(YOUR_STORAGE_CONTROLLER)` before you call `Parse.initialize`.

**An example custom storage controlled is Parse React Native storage controller( which is also async), which could be found at:** https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-JS/blob/master/src/StorageController.react-native.js

- A Sync controller object need to set its `async` property to `0`, and have 
  `getItem, setItem,removeItem, and clear` function implemented
- An Async controller object need to set `async` property to `1`, and have `getItemAsync, setItemAsync,removeItemAsync,clear`implemented

**All you need to do is to follow the react native example and build yourself your own storage controller (with chrome storage api)**, and let Parse to use it instead of use `localStorage`

Original Github issue thread:https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-JS/issues/72

Comment: I would copy over more of the answer; it's perfectly justified here.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly substitute `localstorage` with `chrome.storage`, because one is synchronous and one is not, not to mention different API methods.

You cannot anyhow wrap it in a way that it becomes *fully* synchronous. However, here are some ideas:

1. Work with storage in the background script. There, the domain for `localStorage` is fixed.
2. Make a local synchronous copy of the storage; something like

   ```
   var localData = {};
   chrome.storage.local.get(null, function(data) {
     localData = data;
     doSomethingElse(); // Mind that this is async
   })
   ```

   However, *saving* this cache is going to be a problem. You have to intercept writes and commit it to `chrome.storage` and likewise update it on `onChanged` event - but all that will be asynchronous, which may not work.

In short, if a library uses `localStorage` internally, you won't be able to replace it adequately without rewriting the library or keeping it to background.